# Hardcode Values from Formula in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I work at a library and I write VBA Excel scripts for librarians from time to time to automate tasks, ones revolving around gleaning info from reports usually. I have a data-loving librarian that requested I do an automation of his collection broken down by non-fiction Dewey numbers. I had done this before for his whole collection (he's a children's librarian) by subject. There were only a dozen or so subjects/series so I was able to advance filter each subject criteria from the whole massive library report and make each subject its own table on a new sheet. Then when I populated his Snapshot table with formulas based on each table. Easy peezy and if he saw something that mistakenly got through the filter, deleted it off the table, it would automatically recalculate on the Snapshot table and life was good.

However, now he wants this new snapshot by Dewey numbers. There are 157 Dewey ranges, so making new tables/sheets for each isn't really an option. The problem is when I advance filter the all-report table in place, code in the formula to get the number based on the filter results, it is written as the formula, and as soon as I unfilter or filter for another criteria set, the number changes because it is recalculating based on the dynamic table results. I need the value hardcoded into the cell. This is probably easy, but for the life of me I can't find the answer.

Example: Working from a report that includes all the children's location's non-fiction items, there are 3155 items. First Dewey section is Mysteries 000.000-001.999. There are tons of calculations he wants, but focusing on the first column, he wants to know how many of the items fall into the 000.000-001.999 range.

```
rgNonFict.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, shCrit.Range("A3").CurrentRegion

shNFSnap.Range("C5") = "=SUBTOTAL(3,JRoomNF[BID])"
```

[image]
[image]

When I run the code, I need it to write "11" in the cell instead of the Subtotal formula. How do I do that?

Comment: Look into [Application.WorksheetFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Events-WorksheetFunctions-Shapes/using-excel-worksheet-functions-in-visual-basic) or add `shNFSnap.Range("C5").Value = shNFSnap.Range("C5").Value` after `shNFSnap.Range("C5") = "=SUBTOTAL(3,JRoomNF[BID])"`